# Remove an object from an array without knowing the object's index?

Tags: arrays, core-data, ios8, xcode6, nspredicate

I'm using a switch statement to 1) toggle checkmarks and 2) add/remove a predicate to an array of predicates. Is there a way to remove an object if I know its name, but not its index in the array? If not, what's the workaround? Here's the relevant portion of my code.

```
var colorPredicates: [NSPredicate?] = []

// Switch statement
        case blueCell:
            if (cell.accessoryType == .None) {
                colorPredicates.append(bluePredicate)
                cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
                println(colorPredicates) // debug code to see what's in there
            } else {
                let deleteIndex = find(colorPredicates, bluePredicate) // error: NSPredicate doesn't conform to Equatable.
                muscleGroupPredicates.removeAtIndex(deleteIndex)
                cell.accessoryType = .None
                }
        default:
            println("default case")
```

Comment: Find the object, then remove it.  If you'll be removing more than one, index backwards.  No fancy code required.

Comment: How? That's my question.

Comment: Do you know how to use a loop?  And `if` statements?

Comment: Yes. I think I need a line of code to remove it from the index. I'm going to be adding several things to the array (the switch statement is going to have 20 or so cases in it) and I know the names of the items in the array. I'm just trying to figure out how to find known items at an indeterminate index and remove them if the checkmark is toggled on an interface.

I tried 'let deleteIndex = find(colorPredicates, bluePredicate)' in the else statement and using in 'removeAtIndex: deleteIndex', but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been some frustration with the lack of Swift methods for arrays as well as the lack of the `NSSet` concept. Have you considered casting to `NSArray`?

```
var colorPredicates = [NSPredicate]() as NSArray
```

and

```
colorPredicates.removeObject(bluePredicate)
```

Also, I think that you have a flaw in your data source design: you should not check the `accessoryType` of a cell to do other stuff. That information should be in your data source, not in some arbitrary UI design element.

Comment: The view in question is a UITableView with static cells containing options for the user to check off. The switch statement updates the UI to tell the user whether he/she's selected a predicate and adds/removes it from the array of predicates.

Comment: Digging around a bit further, I found another post to which you replied which hits the nail on the head re: what I'm trying to do.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157088/ios-compound-predicates

Answer (score -3):

I was missing an '!', which generated a compiler error.

I found this post helpful: [Remove an element in an array without hard-coding the index? in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741508/remove-an-element-in-an-array-without-hard-coding-the-index-in-swift)

```
// Switch statement
        case blueCell:
            if (cell.accessoryType == .None) {
                colorPredicates.append(bluePredicate)
                cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
                println(colorPredicates) // debug code to see what's in there
            } else {
                let deleteIndex = find(colorPredicates, bluePredicate)
                colorPredicates.removeAtIndex(deleteIndex!)
                cell.accessoryType = .None
                }
        //more cases within switch statement

        default:
            println("default case")
```